# node crashes after some HMR trggered

Tags: node.js, angular, runtime-error, assertion

posting the full log saved from framedwork FYI as below, might also be a memory leaking issue??

```
assert.js:42 throw new errors.AssertionError({
^
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true
debug log details as below:
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node@8/8.12.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli '/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~prestart: wm-admin@0.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~prestart: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~prestart: PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/node@8/8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/usern/Projects/Vri/wm-admin/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/usern/Projects/i/gopath/bin
8 verbose lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~prestart: CWD: /Users/usern/Projects/Vri/wm-admin
9 silly lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~prestart: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run versions' ]
10 silly lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~prestart: Returned: code: 0 signal: null
11 info lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~start: wm-admin@0.0.0
12 verbose lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/node@8/8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/user/Projects/Vi/wm-admin/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/quin/Projects/Viri/gopath/bin
14 verbose lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/quin/Projects/Viri/wm-admin
15 silly lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c',
15 silly lifecycle 'ng serve --ssl --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --proxy-config proxies/proxy.test.conf.json' ]
16 silly lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1 signal: null
17 info lifecycle wm-admin@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
18 verbose stack Error: wm-admin@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --ssl --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --proxy-config proxies/proxy.test.conf.json`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node@8/8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
18 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node@8/8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
18 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
19 verbose pkgid wm-admin@0.0.0
20 verbose cwd /Users/quin/Projects/Vi/wm-admin
21 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
22 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node@8/8.12.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/npm" "start"
23 verbose node v8.12.0
24 verbose npm v6.4.1
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error wm-admin@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --ssl --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --proxy-config proxies/proxy.test.conf.json`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the wm-admin@0.0.0 start script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

this might also the problem of a nodejs problem that causing too many calls that crashes the system, tried a lot of googling still no one can explain this.

Comment: Side-note, are you in a position to upgrade your nodejs? Because you're on node@v8.12.0 and [current is 11.4.0](https://nodejs.org/en/) ! (It's still maintained, and will be for another year, but several major versions behind.)

Comment: @msanford, thanks but v8 is the latest stable version, I guess v11 still beta, I also tried v11 but project crushes all the time that's why I downgraded to v8

Comment: 11 is the latest stable version. 10 is LTS, so the previous stable version. 8 is just still supported (until Dec 2019) Odd that your previous project crashes though.